# Wordpress htaccess problem

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have some problem with my .htaccess file. Here I am adding my problem. Please help me.

My actual URL is as follows http://localhost/buydualit/?searchitem=toaster&pagenum=1 here by using my .htaccess am rewrited my URL as
http://localhost/buydualit/toaster-1/

My URL rewriting rule is like follows:

```
RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z-0-9,\"'-\/]+\-([0-9]+)\/$ buydualit/index.php?pagenum=$1&searchitem=$2
```

In this rule how can I retrieve **toaster** from  http://localhost/buydualit/toaster-1/
(searchitem=$2 which is not getting)?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put parentheses around the parts of the expression you want. I removed the / char from your set of characters so it'd not grab the buydualit/ part of the url, and put it outside the grabbing section. Finally, the grabbed parts are numbered sequentially, so you have to switch $1 and $2

```
RewriteRule ^buydualit/([A-Za-z-0-9,\"'-]+)-([0-9]+)\/$ buydualit/index.php?pagenum=$2&searchitem=$1
```

Also, this probably doesn't belong here, as it's more of a system administration question than a software development question.